# О местоимениях, обращениях и междометиях

Tags: грамматика

В предложениях с обращениями, в которые входят личные местоимения, а также междометия и частицы, бывает сложно определить их синтаксическую роль. Какой синтаксический разбор является правильным для следующих предложений:

1)Это ты, моя Русь державная, моя родина православная!

(2)Эй () вы, сходитесь, лихие друзья!  Гляньте, как бьётся добыча моя!

(3) Вы, чьи широкие шинели напоминали паруса, чьи шпоры весело звенели и голоса. И чьи глаза, как бриллианты, на сердце вырезали  след,  – очаровательные франты минувших лет!

Спасибо за ответы.

**Обновление**

Спасибо за ответы, но, кажется, тема так и не прояснилась, а еще затуманилась.

**Вопрос 2.** Эй, подойди сюда! Эй ты, подойди сюда! Эй, ты, подойди сюда! Три варианта, и все разные: междометие в роли обращения, междометие+местоимение в роли обращения, местоимение в роли обращения.

Но: Эй, приятель, подойди сюда! Здесь обращением является существительное, перед ним междометие.

Это правильно?

Эй вы! сходитесь, лихие друзья! Текст 1954 года, похоже, что "эй вы"- это междометие, а лихие друзья - обращение. **Может быть, когда называется предмет, именно он становится обращением.**

**Вопрос 3.**

**Вот еще один похожий пример:** О вы, которых ожидает Отечество от недр своих И видеть таковых желает, Каких зовет от стран чужих, О, ваши дни благословенны! Дерзайте ныне ободрены Раченьем вашим показать, Что может собственных Платонов И быстрых разумом Невтонов Российская земля рождать.

**Структура предложения:** обращение "о вы"+ распространенное определение к приложению + содержание высказывания (О, ваши дни благословенны!
Дерзайте ныне ободрены...).

У Цветаевой: обращение "вы" + распространенное определение к приложению (заканчивается восклицательным знаком) + содержание высказывания (Одним ожесточеньем воли вы брали сердце и скалу...).

Или другой вариант: Вы, (определение), очаровательные франты! И далее текст. Тогда Вы - местоимение, очаровательные франты - обращение.

Я никак не могу выбрать.

Ко всему прочему текст **не всегда делится точкой на два предложения**, иногда ставится запятая. **Какой вариант авторский?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вера, обращения, вводные слова не являются членами предложения. Обычно сверху пишут: «обращение», «вводное».

- ### Дополнение

Личные местоимения ты и вы, как правило, не являются обращениями, а выступают в роли подлежащего. Однако ***они могут входить в состав распространенного обращения, пунктуационно выделяясь вместе с ним,*** например: Ну, полноте, полноте, балагур, шутник вы этакий (Тургенев). В редких случаях местоимения ты и вы сами по себе могут выступать в роли обращения, заменяя собой название лица, к которому обращена речь; в этих случаях они выделяются запятыми (в начале и в конце предложения после них может ставиться восклицательный знак); например: Эй, вы, чревовещатели! Марш по теплушкам! (Вс. Иванов); Эй, вы! Кончайте скорее! (Достоевский); Ты! Бери его на мушку (Тренев); Тише, вы! (Антонов).

[Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по пунктуации](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm#%D0%B7_03)

[АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКА](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=782.j68Ng3avw5RG_5itfEOdp5LU50KqNCyZ3UgAaYYGH_E9be49WYRxk9IxxuRxU_Av.92ca0f5ec6da177b29e9e2e260340fef25fd83b7&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9aY8QgvZys2CXOCvRZ8HS-mYqXHcZk1UyA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc1RoUHlrbWJJT05ZUFR3c3Z2QTNyUnRCNmJXanFacHBGVTExUzlyNlBuTk96WTBHMzNQUGpZQ2Z5RW4wMUs3cVhxRTNEREJzMUhDdk1xTzF1em94eVlpM18yV1ZrVTRTZw&b64e=2&sign=654366decc6d9a4405d0c451cd9e5c16&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFLp79Hkq5lEXg1rftu7GFzngBT1g1ww9Z3tpuoJV_sctzaP5OPZRj5BPjQGPt5Np54IwLhikmD8JFh28a_1zqeLHYR1vEXf99UBLOAINprsHI8AE__yk2rvi_wYQdEhGB-jo9KdsTk81ofOZmg_PrbDXCVSTJgw9NEqkw-o46Hpt9JA1yGdtI801LiIYRJAq8A&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpU74gWhcnuS4b6CxITjf2rw4e1Nf3RdHZppJ1895i6Y2UMIeu_3k0v_vxG1t9Uh5pa3yOrGwF2WrLarIFWJ_uELlbcSLG5Srp6wun6prhfzc0H95CP7SQkQVFX5V5CqLW8jMtEeSMU23gsT9KwPYuCR1JwY_0Q186k0H_0OeLune7vpORtURXrMD6KFbTkzPF&l10n=ru&cts=1439715369458&mc=4.781960702863774)

Comment: Обращения, вводные слова, междометия (в своей основной функции) не являются членами предложения, для них надо просто указать границы. В сложных случаях речь идет о МЕСТОИМЕНИЯХ: входят ли они в обращения, каким членом предложения являются, имеют ли синтаксические связи с другими словами/словосочетаниями.

Comment: Серж,  правило не вызывает вопросов, но вы в конкретных примерах определите  синтаксическую роль местоимения.

Comment: В предложении "Это ты" местоимение "ты''  - сказуемое. В последних двух примерах местоимения сами являются обращениями, следовательно, не являются членом предложения.

Comment: Во втором предложении, скорее всего, обращением являются "лихие друзья".  "Эй вы" может быть междометным сочетанием. По поводу третьего предложения существуют разные мнения.  В частности, чем является приложение "очаровательные франты минувших лет"? Может быть, это обращение?

Comment: Вера, антологичный пример: Эй, вы, чревовещатели! Здесь обращение-то "вы".

Comment: Т.е. согласно Розенталю здесь ***вы*** заменяет название лица, к которому обращена речь.

Comment: Вера, а что в последнем примере мешает рассматривать " очаровательные франты минувших лет" как обращение?  Два предложения. В первом обращение - Вы, во втором - приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Ох, умеете Вы спросить...

Навскидку попробую, без гарантии. Хотя за современным полетом мысли угнаться очень сложно. Как только возникает формальная грамматическая неоднозначность (а она есть в каждом предложении в той или иной степени, как Вы и сказали.), в ход идет авторитарное мнение типа "А вот Розенталь (условный) так сказал". Если бы не это не стихи были, еще можно было бы требовать какой-то строгой грамматики...

> 1)Это ты, моя Русь державная, моя родина православная!

Ты - именная часть составного именного сказуемого. Это (есть) ты. Другой вариант невозможен, иначе "это" не привязано. Дальнейшее "моя Русь державная, моя родина православная" можно трактовать или как обращение или как уточняющее приложение. Тут на мой вкус второе вернее (вряд ли смысл высказывания в том чтобы сказать "это ты"), но традиция предписывает считать подобные обороты обращением.

> (2)Эй () вы, сходитесь, лихие друзья! Гляньте, как бьётся добыча моя!

При такой пунктуации (запятая после Вы) заставляет считать "Вы" обращением. Междометие "Эй" дает возможность для такого грамматического разбора. Без "Эй" признать "Вы" обращением было бы очень сложно (опять-таки традиция, формально грамматика допускает). В силу этой роли "Эй" запятая после "Эй" не требуется. Т.е. "Эй Вы" - обращение, дальше идет повелительное наклонение, и еще одно обращение. Иное было бы очень неестественно.  Вот если поставить запятую после "Эй", то после вы уже не нужна, "Вы" становится подлежащим.

> (3) **(I)** Вы, чьи широкие шинели напоминали паруса, чьи шпоры весело звенели
>   и голоса. **(II)** И чьи глаза, как бриллианты, на сердце вырезали след, –
>   очаровательные франты минувших лет!

Вот Марину объяснить логически невозможно. )))
Ей было что-то около 20, когда она это писала, если не ошибаюсь, это возраст экспериментов. Над грамматикой - тоже.

Первое предложение, если не рассматривать в контексте второго, - это что-то типа именительного темы. Или Фразу надо считать неполной с опущенным союзным словом "Вы [есть те], чьи...". Вот второе предложение похитрее будет. Здесь, Полагаю "Вы" подразумевается из первого предложения.

Вы, [такие-сякие] **(I)** и "разэтакие" **(II)**, [есть] очаровательные франты. Получается, что это одна фраза, в угоду правилам стихотворной речи разозванная точкой после первого четверостишия. Тогда имеет "Вы" - подлежашие, "очаровательные франты" - сиысловая часть именного сказуемого с опущенной связкой "быть (*есте* - 2-е лицо мн.)", ну а троекратное "чьи" - придаточные к "Вы". По-другому разложить фразу очень сложно. Можно ли считать это придаточными обращением - не знаю, как и в (1). Мне не хочется считать их таковым. Но, боюсь, и тут традиция будет сильнее.

Вообще с этими местоимениями в подобной функции не всё ясно. Вот сравните "Я, любимый, [написал этот пост]". Ну ясно же, что не обращение. Стоит заменить на "ты" и сразу спорный случай. Рад буду ошибиться - в том смысле, что и умные мира сего не сочтут в "Ты, глупый, плохо в школе учился" глупый обращением. Но стоит поставить существительное, так оно само в звательный падеж просится: "Ты, человече, плохо в школе учился". Короче, вполне может быть какая-то очередная лакуна в формальной грамматике.