# Сочетание "коси коса" в пословице

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, обращение

Почему в пословице "Коси коса, пока роса" нет запятой перед словом "коса"?
Ведь похоже, что "коса" — это обращение, и тогда по правилам русского языка должна ставиться  запятая.
Или же слово "коса" в данном случае по-особому согласуется с глаголом "коси", как в примере местоимением "я"? *Вы вот намусорили, а я убирай за вами.*

Comment: Практически во всех источниках запятая в этом фразеологизме перед словом "коса" стоит. См. примеры: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0,+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisqsPgwMzlAhWoyKYKHbtNCAUQ_AUIFygB&biw=1127&bih=601

Answer (score 1):

**Коси, коса, пока роса; роса долой, и ты домой** ([В. И. Даль. Пословицы русского народа](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/17404/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8)).

*Не докосил хозяин луг,

В поход запоясался,

А в том саду все тот же звук

Как будто раздавался:*
***Коси, коса,

Пока роса,***
Роса долой —
И мы домой.
[А. Твардовский. Дом у дороги](http://fictionbook.in/aleksandr-tvardovskiy-dom-u-dorogi.html)

Коси́ — форма глагола "косить" в повелительном наклонении.
Коса́ — обращение, которое по правилам необходимо выделить запятыми. Написание без обособления является ошибочным.

*В ней прямо по рельсам шпарь,

И не во сне – наяву.

Людей **не коси, косарь,**

А лучше коси траву.*
А. Лекомцев

Горшочек, кашу вари! Горшочек, больше не вари! (братья Гримм. Горшок каши)
«Беги, Алиса, беги» — название спектакля.

Почему нет запятой? Вполне возможно, что поговорку произносят так: *Ко́сит коса пока роса.*
В этом предложении запятые не требуются.

Answer (score 0):

**Коса**-это **обращение**, и здесь ставится запятая.

В предложении "Вы вот намусорили, а **я** убирай за вами"? 
"Я" является **местоимением**, а **местоимение** не может быть **обращением**.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте галочкой (слева от ответа).

Comment: *местоимение не может быть обращением* — Эй, Вы, запомните! Любое правило имеет исключения :)

Comment: Прошу простить за такую грубую ошибку.
Но не могли бы вы назвать эти исключения
чтобы я больше не ошибался.

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии я привёл пример, когда местоимение "Вы" выступает в роли самостоятельного обращения (прозвучало не очень вежливо, но это только ради примера). Пример взят из книги "Грамматический метод обучения русскому правописанию".

Comment: Обязательно её прочитаю.

Comment: @Cloud - Вы не сделали ошибки. Местоимения в нормальной речи не может быть обращением. Представленный пример весьма спорен и не может быть однозначно интерпретирован как обращение.  Вот тут представлены два подхода https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417489 к трактовке подобных конструкций.

Comment: У вас правда есть другая неточность. "Я"  является местоимение не "в предложении" а безотносительно к нему, то есть изначально, просто как часть речи.